# where is dist-folder as used by grunt when running yo angular

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I used yeoman to scaffold an angular app like so:

```
yo angular --minsafe
```

Now, I'm trying to set up jade > html compilation using grunt-contrib-jade but I don't understand the huge Gruntfile.js generated for me.

There is a mountFolder function:

```
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
  return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};
```

...and a yeoman config object:

```
  // configurable paths
  var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };
```

when running `grunt server` chrome opens up and I get served my page. But where is this magic 'dist' folder that's been served? I can't find it on disk...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dist folder is only created when you run the `build` grunt task. While you run `grunt server`, you get the combined contents of `app/` and the `.tmp/` folder served to you, whereby `.tmp` contains temporary build artifacts like compiled SASS stylesheets, compiled CoffeeScript files and it would be the place you want to keep your compiled jade output.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get the concept that you could combine `app/` and `.tmp/`.